# Recommendations for limit switches for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm looking for a limit switch to use with the Arduino. In my project I want to count how many times my [turntable](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0220/4654/products/slider1_large.jpeg?v=1420208854) makes a full 360° rotation. An object (wheel, pipe, whatever) will be sticking out the side of the turntable and when it comes in contact with the limit switch that will be right next to the turntable, it should notify the Arduino.

Any suggestions on which limit switch I should get?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want a *limit switch*? A limit switch is used to stop the motion at a specific point, not count rotations. For that you would use some kind of encoder, interrupter, hall effect sensor, reed switch, etc.

Comment: Indeed, a magnet under the turntable could activate a hall-effect sensor as it passes over it.

Comment: Maybe tell us a bit more about what you want to accomplish, then we can think about the problem – rather than just think about a device. From the photo of the turntable I'm thinking that you're planning to do object movies or panoramas. For that you might actually do better with a stepper motor.

Comment: I'd use a photo reflective sensor, and stick a white dot on the side of the turntable. You could add dots to get half, quarter, etc. rotation resolution

Comment: @Majenko I do want it to send a signal to my Arduino to stop the electricity going to the turntable, and then hopefully each time that signal occurs the Arduino can just increase a counter.

Comment: @NickGammon  I'll look into that.  Thanks!

Comment: @dlu I'm trying to do 360 photography, and the turntable needs to stop at the exact same spot in each rotation.

Comment: @Gerben I'll look into that for sure.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you could get it to stop at the same location using a regular turntable. As the turntable will continue spinning a bit after you kill the power to the motor (due to inertia). I think you would be better of replacing the DC motor in the turntable with a stepper-motor.

Comment: Besides the problem @Gerben mentioned  you may find that a switch does not give you the precision of position that you want/need. Definitely consider a stepper if you can.

Comment: Great points.  You're both right. I'll move forward with a stepper-motor for version 2 of my setup.  
I'm just going this route because I was provided with an automated turntable to first work with.  
Maybe I can open it up and change out some parts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A $2 microswitch with a roller would be OK for a million revs or so.

[image]

You would put a little ramp on the diameter and use it to trigger the switch.

Non-contact magnetic or optical could be better for more cycles or faster operation.

Comment: Literally a million? That's impressive.

Comment: Honeywell's PDF at http://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-micro-switch-sx-basic-switch-product-sheet-004968-2-en.pdf says 10,000,000 cycles.    But one probably needs to check the datasheet.  Googling a bit, I saw some specs of 1M-5M cycles on a single switch, depending on load, but also some cheap mini ones rated for 10,000 cycles.    Also, for a 33rpm audio turntable even a million isn't long: 1,000,000/33/60/24 = 21 days

Comment: @DaveX do you have a link to a brand in particular you recommend?

Comment: I do not have a recommendation on the brand.

Comment: Beware that a physical switch will probably exhibit **contact bounce**.  One can filter that in software, but it requires thought.

Comment: Well, @Dlu; @Dave X is right on this point, if your project involves being used for longer duration including testing etc. My suggestion would be dont go for this solution at all. Else if its just for a couple of 10s of usage, this shouldn't be a issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a limit switch a hall effect sensor with a moving magnet is an optimal soltuntion since it is contact less there will be no frictional side effects on your application.

But there is one more better way to it, try to use an rotary encoder, something like a 400/600 ppr should also be fine for this, doing this way you have more positional data of the turntable,

You can calculate no of turn, arcs etc.

For eg:

1. A 400ppr would give you a resolution of 0.9 degree per pulse, and
2. 600ppr would give you 0.6degree per pulse of accuracy.

Although you can go for even higher ppr encoders but you can get these at very low cost.

Pic from: https://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/400BM-Rotary-Encoder-Module-LPD3806-360-6mm-Shaft-Arduino-Pi-Flux-Workshop-/112607725039?_mwBanner=1

Note: Just an example, price may be different at other webites, haven't checked the price while writing this solution.
[image: A 400ppr rotary encoder]